# How to rewrite function that uses string interpolation for VS 2013?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

I am using visual studio 2017 but on our server we use visual studio 2013. I keep getting an error that says unexpected character `$` and I did some research and VS2013 doesn't support String interpolation. Is there any other of getting the values from the capture groups?

```
    public static String RoundParams(String flashingParams)
    {
        var regex = new Regex("(?<![a-zA-Z])(?<letter>[a-zA-Z])=(?<value>[^,]+)");

        var result = regex.Replace(flashingParams, m =>
        {
            var newValue = m.Groups["letter"].Value.Any(char.IsUpper)
                ? RoundDoubleTo(Convert.ToDouble(m.Groups["value"].Value), 2)
                : RoundDoubleTo(Convert.ToDouble(m.Groups["value"].Value), 16);

            return $"{m.Groups["letter"].Value}={newValue}";
        });
        return result;
    }
```

Comment: Alternatively to converting to string.Format calls, you could add the Microsoft.Net.Compilers nuget package to the project and let that handle compilation. Earlier versions of VS will show the error in intellisense but it should compile just fine. This can be done through the Project->Enable Language Features menu option.

Comment: Why are you using Visual Studio on a server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

String interpolation is just a nicer syntax for `String.Format`:

```
return String.Format("{0}={1}", m.Groups["letter"].Value, newValue);
```

Answer (score 2):

String interpolation can be replaced by a call to `string.Format`:

```
return string.Format("{0}={1}", m.Groups["letter"].Value, newValue);
```

or in this simple case by string concatenation:

```
return m.Groups["letter"].Value + "=" + newValue;
```